# How do you deal with individual pixels in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm planning on making a platformer style game using Sprite-Kit with Objective-C, and I'm trying to plan out exactly how I'm going to do things before I start coding.

I think it'll most likely be tile based but I'm not 100% on that yet.

I'm thinking about how I'll deal with slopes. I want my slopes to be irregular, not the same angle every time. I heard about a method in which you measure the pixels one pixel to the right of the character (assuming the character is moving right). If the ground has gotten higher up, you move the character up by that many pixels and right by one pixel. This could be done more than once before each frame is rendered depending on the character's speed.

I'm wondering how this would be applied in SpriteKit. Is it possible to measure pixels in SpriteKit?

Comment: This question is likely off-topic regarding to StackOverflow rules. Please see  [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Pixels aren't really used in SpriteKit from what I can tell.  What may suit you better is something from some 3D games where you have a "capsule" shaped physics body on the player, and then "push" it around on the terrain.

Comment: If you have gravity enabled, then just have your player move in an up left/right direction,  gravity will push them down before the user sees it,  no need to measure pixels, just decide what is the max height that a slope can be before it becomes a wall, and have the person move up max height - 1 pixels